# How to navigate to new screen after redux action?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation, expo

I have a simple component that when you click a button, it calls the create new game endpoint via a redux action. On the response, I want to navigate to a new screen with a param from the response of the API call.

My component looks like this:

```
const HomeScreen = ({
  navigation, 
  room,
  user,
  newGame
}) => {

  return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Start new game"
          onPress={async () => {
            await newGame({ _id: user._id })
            navigation.navigate('Lobby', { roomId: room._id })
          }}
        />
      </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    room: state.room,
    user: state.user
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  newGame
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

`room._id` only gets set once newGame has completed so calling it in the onClick handler doesn't make senes.

Also, calling it in the render method like:

```
if(room){
  navigation.navigate('Lobby', { roomId: room._id })
}
```

means that this just continuously gets called on each render and end up in some infinite loop.

I'm guessing I need to call the navigate in some sort of redux action? But I'm not sure how this can be achieved considering navigation relies on the navigation prop passed to each child component of  my navigation stack.

How can I force a screen navigation after a redux action?

Comment: And if you use `useEffect` with room passed as a dependency? Basically the same as you are trying to do in render, but inside `useEffect` instead.

Comment: Yeah I could potentially do something within useEffect to check if `prevProps.room._id !== props.room._id`. Seems a messy though and I would have thought there is a more simple way of handilng a navigation to a new screen.